# How to properly size an object using constraints in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm fairly new to Xcode and I am trying to create a simple app that is universal to support all iPhone screen sizes.

I'm testing this on an iPhone 5 screen and iPhone 6 screen.

I have the following constraints for the background `UIImageView` object, which expands to support both screen sizes perfectly.

[image]

For the View object colored in gray, I set the following constraints:

[image]

However, when I tested it on my iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, the View object remains the same size. It doesn't resize proportionate to both phone screen sizes because you can see how much space the View object takes as shown:

[image]            [image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the gray view to do? Did you add any other constraints besides the centerX and CenterY? You need to define its size too.

Comment: If I define the gray view's size, i.e. it's width and height, doesn't that size remain static regardless of screen size?

Comment: It depends on how you define it. You can give the view left and right spacing constraints to the edges of the superview, which will make it expand to the width of the screen. For height, you can either give the view an aspect ratio, or define it in relationship to the superview height if you want it to be taller on a taller screen.

Comment: the aspect ratio works!...thanks rdelmar!...I'm curious to try your 2nd method of defining the relationship, how would I go about doing that?..Sorry I'm not too familiar with this yet.

Comment: You need to select the view and the superview (best done from the scene list) and then pick "equal heights" from the pin menu. Then select that constraint, and edit it to change the multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

For Gray view, besides CEnterX & CenterY, you need to define height constraints and Leading space and Trailing zero with 0 constant.